# How to iterate pages for pagination if its more than certain number in Flask without SQLAlchemy?

Tags: flask, pagination, peewee

I want to create pagination for my blog using Peewee instead of SQLAlchemy as I seen every tutorial on it, so I'm trying to use something different. I rarely see any tutorial on it. I updated a previous question but there were no responses so I decided to create a new post. Now I already manage to display the pages using range:

```
{% for page_num in range(1, pagination.get_page_count() + 1) %}
    {% if pagination.get_page() == page_num %}
        <a href="./?{{ request.args|clean_querystring('page', page=page_num) }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ page_num }}</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="./?{{ request.args|clean_querystring('page', page=page_num) }}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">{{ page_num }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[image: Pagination]

What I'm trying to do now is splitting the pages similar to SQLAlchemy "iter_pages" threshold:

[image: Iter pages]

Is there a way I could do this using range, or do I need to use something else?

Comment: You just need to decide how many pages you want to show, then do a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can fiddle around with something like this:

```
def get_page_range(page, total, show=5):
    start = max((page - (show // 2)), 1)
    stop = min(start + show, total) + 1
    start = max(min(start, stop - show), 1)
    return list(range(start, stop)[:show])
```

Example output for pages 1-10 where there are 10 total pages of results, and 5 buttons should be shown:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(i, get_page_range(i, 10, 5))
```

Output:

```
1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
4 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
5 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
6 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
7 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
8 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
9 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
10 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: I forgot to ask. Where would would I put this method?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/a6198b96f475a2ee9687f36eda1cbb539907c56a